# SAX Parser, new lines being removed after parsing, can I keep them in? (&#13;)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

I'm unsure on how complicated or easy this issue might be since this is my first project with XML parsing and therefore using the SAX parser.

When pulling down XML from a server, I can see in the XML there are a few `&#13;` in the text, a carriage return character, or new line. After the XML has gone through the SAX parser it comes out the other end without those characters.

It comes out as a string and when I add it to a TextView it's just one big block of text, which is obviously not something I want.

Is there a way for me to parse the XML and still keep the `&#13;` characters? My idea was to do a `String.replace("&#13;", "\n");` right before adding it to the TextView, therefore making use of new lines.

If there is a better way I would love to know but just being able to use `&#13;` would be helpful too.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: what you mean by *After the XML has gone through the SAX parser it comes out the other end without those characters.*

Comment: After it has been parsed. I parse everything into an ArrayList<String> then call it from there in any activity I need. When I call the String for this bit of text, the new lines have been removed. For example before it gets parsed I see "Next Item&#13;&#13;Some other text here". After it has been parsed and I try to set it to a textview I see "Next ItemSome other text here".

Comment: I see.. could be either an error at parsing time or the textview is ignoring &#13; for some reason. Can you try to wrap the text inside Html.fromHtml ?

Comment: It's not the TextView because I printed it out in a Log and got the same result. Parsing it seems to remove these characters.

Comment: Then post the handler

Comment: Yeah that's what I think, so are you saying that I should use Html.fromHtml when going through parsing?

Comment: no red, you should not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting the parser I am converting my HTTP result into a string, so before I parse I do a `String.replace("&#13;", "&#10;");`

After parsing new lines show up correctly. I guess the parser ignores carriage return in favour or new lines. Which makes sense I guess.

Hopefully this helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

XML parsers are required to normalize line endings, so CR and CRLF sequences are all turned into LF (CR=x0D, LF=x0A) before presentation to the application.

If you want to retain the CR characters (why??) you should represent them as numeric character references, that is `&#13;`

Comment: I want to retain the characters so that I can have line breaks in the text, paragraphs basically. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The normalization of line endings will replace CR with NL, so there are still line endings there. But perhaps this isn't the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Yeah maybe. I'll have a chat with the server guys and see what we can come up with.